# Is there a way when we focus in input then it display in above of soft keyboard (WebView)?

Tags: android, android-webview, android-softkeyboard

I use HTML website to load in WebView, but when the user clicks in TextBox, then it hides under the keyboard. so what will be suggestion for doing this?

Answer (score 0):

1. **Staus Bar Present**

   If your activity is not a full screen activity then you can use `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`or
       `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"`
   in your `AndroidManifest.xml` to achieve this.
2. **For Full Screen Activity**

   First method will not work for full screen activity. So use have to create a utility 
   class for do this manually

   Create public class **WindowResize.java**

   ```
   public  class WindowResize{
      public static void assistActivity(Activity activity) {
       new WindowResize(activity);
      }

      private View mChildOfContent;
      private int usableHeightPrevious;
      private FrameLayout.LayoutParams frameLayoutParams;

      private WindowResize(final Activity activity) {
       FrameLayout content = activity.findViewById(android.R.id.content);
       mChildOfContent = content.getChildAt(0);
       mChildOfContent.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
           public void onGlobalLayout() {
               possiblyResizeChildOfContent(activity);
           }
       });
       frameLayoutParams = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) mChildOfContent.getLayoutParams();
      }

     private void possiblyResizeChildOfContent(Activity activity) {
       //Visible height
       int usableHeightNow = computeUsableHeight();
       if (usableHeightNow != usableHeightPrevious) {
           //Total window size. We have to decrement the SoftNavigation button height from total height if there any
           int usableHeightSansKeyboard = mChildOfContent.getRootView().getHeight() - getNavigationButtonHeight(activity);
           int heightDifference = usableHeightSansKeyboard - usableHeightNow;
           if (heightDifference > (usableHeightSansKeyboard / 4)) {
               // keyboard  visible
               frameLayoutParams.height = usableHeightSansKeyboard - heightDifference;
           } else {
               // keyboard  hidden
               frameLayoutParams.height = usableHeightSansKeyboard;
           }
           mChildOfContent.requestLayout();
           usableHeightPrevious = usableHeightNow;
         }
       }

     //Usable height in current window.
     private int computeUsableHeight() {
       Rect r = new Rect();
       mChildOfContent.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);
       return (r.bottom - r.top);
     }

     //SoftInput navigation buttons height.
     private int getNavigationButtonHeight(Activity activity) {
       // getRealMetrics is only available with API 17 and +
       DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
       activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
       int usableHeight = metrics.heightPixels;
       activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRealMetrics(metrics);
       int realHeight = metrics.heightPixels;
       if (realHeight > usableHeight)
           return realHeight - usableHeight;
       else
           return 0;

     }
   }
   ```

add `WindowResize.assistActivity(this);` in main activity which contains corresponding webview.